# Cambiar imagen de ImageView desde FIle chooser JAVAFX

Tags: javafx

No consigo que se vea la imaen cargada en la ImageView.

```
@FXML
void cambiarImgPerfil(ActionEvent actionEvent) throwsjava.io.IOException{

    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("Open File");
    chooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files","*.bmp", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif")); 
    File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
    if(file != null) {
            //String imagepath = file.toURI().toURL().toString();


            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString()); 
            imgPerfil = new ImageView(image);

                                                                                                       System.out.println("height:"+image.getHeight()+"\nWidth:"+image.getWidth());
           imgPerfil.setImage(image);
           System.out.println(imgPerfil.isVisible());
    }
    else
    {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText("Please Select a File");
    /*alert.setContentText("You didn't select a file!");*/
        alert.showAndWait();
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta hacerlo de esta forma:

```
byte[] btImagen = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
Image img = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(btImagen), 199, 199, false, false);
imgPerfil.setImage(img);
```

Comment: Se considera una respuesta de baja calidad solo poner código, elabora un poco más tu respuesta